# What is the problem in domain in Server Actions

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I used ir.actions.server model for add an option in action menu item.

Main purpose for using this is to run python code from here.Here i don't want to return a tree or form view here , so i used this method.

I need to add an option only in vendor bills form, but the option is set both invoice and supplier form.

```
    <record id="account_invoice_accrual_entries_vendor_bill_non_po_action" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Accrual Entries</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_account_invoice"/>
        <field name="domain">[('type','in',('in_invoice'))]</field>
         <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">
            if records:
                records.action_accrual_entries_vendor_bill()
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="account_invoice_accrual_entries_vendor_bill_non_po" model="ir.values">
        <field name="model_id" ref="account.model_account_invoice"/>
        <field name="name">Accrual Entries</field>
        <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
        <field name="key">action</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
         <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,' + str(ref('account_invoice_accrual_entries_vendor_bill_non_po_action'))" />
    </record>
```

**This is the code i try to add domain only for vendor bills. But the option visible in both vendor bills and customer invoice.**

anyone knows what is the mistake in my code .??

Comment: try `<field name="domain">[('type','=','in_invoice')]</field>`

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for comment. I tried like this but not working. option shows in both views

Comment: I don't think there is a possibility in Odoo 10 to bind an action to a subset of records of a model or to an window action which is used before showing this action. It will always be shown in the action menu, if the binding model is shown/seen. So you probably have to filter your records in the code, and users can use the action "everywhere" but it will do nothing on customer invoices...

Comment: @CZoellner: Thanks for the comment and valuable information.I set a function that not affected in customer invoices.